# UITableview slow scroll and increase ram after some scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

this is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hourCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...


    cell.textLabel.text=hoursarray[indexPath.row];

    if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UIButton *buttonOff = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    buttonOff.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    UIButton *buttonT1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    buttonT1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    UIButton *buttonT2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    buttonT2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;      
    buttonOff.frame = CGRectMake(130, 5, 40, 34);
    [buttonOff setTitle:@"OFF" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonOff addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonOFFTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buttonT1.frame = CGRectMake(190, 5, 40, 34);
    [buttonT1 setTitle:@"T1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonT1 addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonT1Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buttonT2.frame = CGRectMake(250, 5, 40, 34);
    [buttonT2 setTitle:@"T2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonT2 addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonT2Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:buttonOff];
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:buttonOff];
    buttonOff.tag=indexPath.row;

    [cell addSubview:buttonT1];
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:buttonT1];
    buttonT1.tag=indexPath.row;

    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:buttonT2];
    [cell addSubview:buttonT2];
    buttonT2.tag=indexPath.row;

    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[datiProgrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+48*day]] isEqual:@"1"])
    {
        buttonOff.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        buttonT1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        buttonT2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[datiProgrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+48*day]] isEqual:@"2"])
    {
        buttonOff.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        buttonT1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        buttonT2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[datiProgrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+48*day]] isEqual:@"3"])
    {
        buttonOff.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        buttonT1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        buttonT2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
return cell;
```

}

The fact is that after two or three scrolls (fast and smooth) the scrolling goes slow and crappy and the ram used increase.
I tried to put if(cell==nill) but I'm using storyboard and the cell is never nill

Am I wrong in something?

Thanks a lot,
N.

Comment: Just a thought, why do you have to create and delete buttons for every cell. You can just create the buttons in story board and then only set the background in cellForRow and if you don't need some of the buttons you can hide them

Comment: Yes I'm using storyboard. I will try to create buttons directly on it thanks

Comment: Sorry just so that you said that you are using storyboard.  Let me know if that works better.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Illegal Configuration: The buttonOff outlet from the CHRHoursListTableViewController to the UITableViewCell is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. I'm creating an outlet

Comment: I don't think you can just wire up the buttons like that.  You would have to create custom UITableViewCell and wire up the buttons there.

Comment: Thanks ! done. Created custom tableview cell and added button to it. Followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0Af0fVb4lo

Comment: Great.  Is it working better now?

Comment: I see a couple problems here and am working on writing up an answer. (And you don't need to use the interface builder like Yan's saying if you don't want to.)

Comment: Yes, working good. Added a class Tableview and outlet to the buttons. Imported class on tableview controller and instantiated cell of this class. Scrolling is very smooth no ram now. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here.

The whole point of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is to reuse your cells *and* their content. But I see you've used this line:

```
if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

to remove the cell content at every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is a waste of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Nevertheless, your logic is *almost* correct. You can remove the subviews and create new subviews without having the incremental memory issues you're describing. The problem is you've made a small error:

You're adding the `UIButton`s directly to the cell's view, for example

```
[cell addSubview:buttonOff];
```

but removing the subviews of the cell's *content* view:

```
[cell.contentView subviews]
```

(You're also using `bringSubviewToFront:` ineffectively for this same reason.)

Because of this mistake, you're not actually removing the buttons at every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as you've intended so as you scroll back and forth, buttons are being added one on top of another on top of another, thus increasing memory usage.

To fix this problem, whether you add and remove from `cell` or `cell.contentView`, you have to be consistent.

All that aside though, since the content of your cells is very similar, I highly recommend you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in the way it was intended by actually reusing your cells' content.

Comment: @Lindsey I was thinking that there had to be something that was slowing down UI.  Adding few buttons shouldn't be a problem in a grand scheme of things.  Great catch and explanation! :)

Comment: @Yan Thanks :) Yeah, it was easy to miss. Took me a while to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. This is the code working good. I added a TableViewCell class that contains only the outlet to the buttons (added buttons graphically in the storyboard):

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CHRTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOFF;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonT1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonT2;

@end
```

then instantiated cell on tableview controller and pointing to the outlet changed the button's aspect:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CHRTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hourCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...


    cell.textLabel.text=hoursarray[indexPath.row];


    cell.buttonOFF.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.buttonOFF.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    cell.buttonOFF.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

    cell.buttonT1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.buttonT1.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    cell.buttonT1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

    cell.buttonT2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.buttonT2.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    cell.buttonT2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

    [cell.buttonOFF setTitle:@"OFF" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonOFF addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonOFFTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.buttonT1 setTitle:@"T1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonT1 addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonT1Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.buttonT2 setTitle:@"T2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonT2 addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonT2Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.buttonOFF.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.buttonT1.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.buttonT2.tag=indexPath.row;


    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[datiProgrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+48*day]] isEqual:@"1"])
    {

        cell.buttonOFF.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:60.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        cell.buttonT1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.buttonT2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[datiProgrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+48*day]] isEqual:@"2"])
    {
        cell.buttonOFF.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.buttonT1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:60.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];;
        cell.buttonT2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[datiProgrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+48*day]] isEqual:@"3"])
    {
        cell.buttonOFF.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.buttonT1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.buttonT2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:60.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];;
    }

return cell;
```

}